# AS3/XML - How to get a list of nodes that have a certain tag with value X

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, search, e4x

I've got an XML file that has many nodes along the lines of this:

```
<animal name="dog">
    ...
    <tag>mammal</tag>
    <tag>brown</tag>
</animal>
```

I'm hoping to use the `tag` node as part of a search function for certain animals. So I could collate a list of all mammals for example.

I've been playing around with something along the lines of this:

`myXML..tag=="mammal"` or `myXML.*.tag=="mammal"`

Also tried switching `tag` to have an attribute (eg: `<tag type="brown"/>`), and then searching using something like `myXML..tag.@type=="brown"`,  but alas, both methods trace out to something useless like "false".

I don't particularly want to have to loop through every node to try and find this, as I have too many that need to be searched quite often. So if there was some magical way (might not have to be XML) that I can enter a search value or tag, and it return a list or array of every `animal.@name` that has the specified tag.

This has kind of been asked before, but not quite like this and never really answered (that I could find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one,

```
var xml:XML = <animal name="dog">               
        <tag type="mammal">mam</tag>
        <tag type="brown">br</tag>                      
        <tag type="black">bl</tag>                      
        <tag type="black">black</tag>
      </animal>;

var attr:String = "black";              
var val:String = "b";
var resultList:XMLList = xml..tag.(@type == attr).(toString().indexOf(val)>-1);
```

o/p:

```
<tag type="black">
  bl
</tag>
<tag type="black">
  black
</tag>
```

Anyhow you always use loop to get better performance.[e4X Slow](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Photos_Graphics/Web_Graphics/Macromedia_Flash/ActionScript/A_2107-20-Tips-to-Optimize-your-ActionScript.html). Read carefully 15 point.

Based on your comment:

```
var myXML:XML = <animal name="dog">                                     
                         <tag type="mammal">true</tag>                  
                         <tag type="brown">true</tag>                   
                         <tag type="black">true</tag>                                   
                    </animal>;                  

                for each(var tag:XML in myXML..tag) //no matter of depth Note here
                {
                    if (tag.@type == "mammal") 
                    { 
                        trace(tag.parent().@name); 
                        trace(tag.text()); 
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: The above didn't work still, but on your advice, I'm going to try to loop through it instead. But so far, no luck. Using an XML with tags like `<tag type="mammal">true</tag>`, and looping through with:
    for each(animal:XML in myXML) {
        if (animal.tag.@type == "mammal") {
            trace(animal.@name);
        }
    }

However, nothing shows up. Nothing traces out.

Comment: First one woks fine for me and better you can put breakpoint the then check the value of resultList. Problem in your loop and animal xml in your whole XML so loop always execute once. Can you define your XML structure. Updated answer might be useful.

Comment: Beautiful. Accepted. Your updated loop function works perfectly. Thank you, you've been very helpful and prompt.